# Does anyone know what's the algorithm used behind the Photoshop "Match Color" function?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, photoshop

Does anyone know what's the algorithm used behind the Photoshop "Match Color" function?

It seems it's not just a histogram equalization.